# What neural network architecture can I use to take advantage of clusters in the data?

Tags: neural-networks, clustering

What neural network architectures can I use to take advantage of clusters in the data? In particular, I'm interested in doing a classification problem in which I believe that each cluster behaves slightly differently but that there are still trends across the data points across all clusters.

My current thoughts are to augment the data points to use a one-hot encoding based on which cluster each data point is in, but I'm not sure that this is effective.

Comment: Are the clusters already identified and you want to use the cluster ID as a feature? Or are you saying your data appears to have clusters and you want to create an architecture that will detect and exploit this structure?

Comment: The clusters are already identified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A neural net with one hidden layer is 
$$
y = g(a(X\Gamma_1)\Gamma_2)
$$
where $g()$ is your output activation and $a()$ is your relu or whatever.

So you have a cluster variable $c$ that you can turn into a matrix of dummies $C$.  Is cluster membership predictive of $y$?  (Go run a logistic regression right now if you don't know the answer.  You should have done this first.)

Just modify your neural net:
$$
y = g(C\beta + a(X\Gamma_1)\Gamma_2)
$$

If you think that there are nonlinear interactions between the clusters and $X$ you can do 
$$
y = g(C\beta + a([C,X]\Gamma_1)\Gamma_2)
$$

Heck, if you think there are linear interactions between the network output and C you could do

$$
y = g(C\beta + a(X\Gamma_1)\Gamma_2 + (C\times a(X\Gamma_1))\Gamma_3)
$$

All of this is easy-enough to implement in Keras using the functional API.  You need multiple inputs if you want parametric structure.